# Chrome CSS3 border-bottom transition bug

Tags: css, html

Im having a problem inside of Chrome only, tested this inside of Opera, FF, Safari and it all works fine.

I know there was a bug with Chrome 17 with transitions on visited links so I even included that *thought to be fix*

There is still not animation for the transition on hover for border-bottom.

any clues? am I just not seeing something? I've read around and it all seems to be talking about the color of the text, while i'm trying to transition in the border-color.

I tried to animate in border-bottom from none to 1px solid #9ecd41 but found that in all browsers except firefox had a funky jagged animation where it kinda bounced.

any help would be awesome, attached is the code i'm working with.

Ok here is my html

```
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

And here is my CSS

```
nav {
float: right;
height: auto;
width: auto;
padding: 25px;
}

ul.nav {
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: visible;
}

.nav > li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.nav > li:last-child {
margin-right: 5px;     
}



/* non-visited links: Chrome transition bug fix */
.nav > li > a:visited {
color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-family: "proxima-nova-condensed",sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
font-smooth: always;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333; /* CSS3 transition */

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

/* visited links: Chrome transition bug fix */
.nav > li > a {
color: #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-family: "proxima-nova-condensed",sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
font-smooth: always;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333; /* CSS3 transition */

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}


.nav > li > a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #9ecd41;
}

.nav > li > a:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f96d10;
}
```

Comment: btw, I even tested this inside of JSfiddle with someone elses code and it worked one second then changed tabs, changed back and nothing worked, no transitions... without even clicking on any links to create a :visited state.

Comment: I don't know what you want us to do. These are bugs. These are also **experimental features**. I wouldn't expect them to work perfectly in all browsers yet.

Comment: Solved! I tried to answer my own question, but I dont have 100 points yet. :) Just styled the <li> the way I would of styled the li with widths/heights/padding/border etc and then just styled the link to fill the li and just styled the links color and font properties. Chrome has small bug on border-bottom for link transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just styled the `<li>` the way I would of styled the li with widths/heights/padding/border etc and then just styled the link to fill the li and just styled the links colour and font properties. Chrome has small bug on border-bottom for link transitions

Answer (score 0):

This aught to be an easy fix.
As far as I can see your problem lies by where you put the transition in.
With chrome it needs to be added to the at most parent.

Try adding it here:

> ```
> .nav > li {
>    display: inline-block;
>    margin-right: 20px;
> }
> ```

Also add the declaration for the -webkit- elements
for ex.

> ```
> .nav > li {
>    display: inline-block;
>    margin-right: 20px;
>    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
>    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
>    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
>    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
>    transition: all .2s ease-in;
>    -webkit-transition-property: all;
>    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
>    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
> }
> ```

See if this works and if not I'll try to build something similar and work on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Bootstrap 4 navbar component. My menu links had border-bottom and starting from the second one, all were invisible during menu opening on mobile.
Fixed it with `transform: rotate(0);` on the element with the border-bottom.